# How do I remove a large number of revisions from Subversion

Tags: svn

I have large repository that I would like to remove the oldest 6,000 revisions.  It would be great if I could also remove unneeded groups of revisions in the middle also.

I have figured out how to eliminate the unwanted files and branches, but I am still left a lot of unneeded revisions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **svnadmin dump** command you can create a dump file from arbitrary revisions and after this filter it to in/exclude certain paths.
The syntax is:

```
svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH [-r LOWER[:UPPER]] [--incremental]
```

an example: you want to exclude the revisions 10-99 from your repostory:

```
svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH -r 0:9  > my_dump_file.dmp
svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH -r 100:HEAD  > my_dump_file.dmp --incremental
```

There are some problems:

- changes of files in rev after 100  you have added in rev 10-99 in my example will create an error message you need to remove them from repo *before*
- removement of files you use later as copy source will also result in errors in dump files.

Both restrictions you can mostly circumvent but it takes more iterations of dump/filter/load cycles and so more time. It is up to you when your time is up to handle these bordercases.

use svnbook to read detailed info of [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump) and [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter)